# CSS/javascript for making div same size as page/document

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Setting

```
#myDiv
{
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    left:0;
}
```

makes the div the same size as the *visible* page, but if you have an active scrollbar then the div isn't actually the same size as the complete page.

Is there a way around this in CSS?

Or if not, what is the simplest javascript/jQuery solution.

**Edit:** here is a jsFiddle as people seem to be misunderstanding the problem. Scroll down!
http://jsfiddle.net/QEzbP/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Forget height and width. Add bottom and right properties:

```
#myDiv
{
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    bottom:0;
    right: 0;
}
```

That will fill the page completely.

EDIT: Note that the container of the div must be position:relative, so in that case the body of the HTML document would have to be given that rule:

```
body {
 position: relative;  
}
```

Comment: @robusto nice solution , i will go to office and check if i gave bottom and right on my css , if this works i will change the code,really simple and nice solution.

Comment: Good choice. Also, there is a good A List Apart article on this - http://www.alistapart.com/articles/conflictingabsolutepositions. If you go this route, I would recommend reading the article to achieve complete, cross-browser compliance.

Comment: hmmm this doesn't work on any browser i've just tested it on. Did anyone even verify this before upvoting?

Comment: It definitely works. I have used many times. Again, I would recommend reading the article I mentioned in the previous comment. It will give you much more information and probably point out what your doing wrong.

Comment: @stjowa: no, really, it doesn't work. see for yourself http://jsfiddle.net/QEzbP/1/

Comment: @fearofawhackplanet: I forgot to mention that the container has to be position: relative, so if you add `.body {
 position: relative;  
}` to your jsfiddle you'll see it works fine.

Comment: @Robusto: Yes, that's it. Might want to update the answer for future views.

Answer (score 2):

I did something like below in my project , it should be same for you

```
    var docHeight = Math.max(
     $(document).height(),
     $(window).height(),
     /* For opera: */
     document.documentElement.clientHeight
     );
     var docWidth = Math.max(
     $(document).width(),
     $(window).width(),
     /* For opera: */
     document.documentElement.clientWidth
     );
     $("#VbackgroundPopup").css({
     "height":docHeight,
     "width":docWidth
 });
```

Comment: you can mention #myDiv in place of #VbackgroundPopup

Comment: @earofawhackplanet for only IE was giving problem so i did above code , is it same for you. Firefox and chrome should occupy full screen if you mention 100% width and 100% height.

Comment: +1 i prefer the pure CSS solution but this is useful to know anyway

Answer (score 0):

Yeah it is the same size, because the scrollbar actually makes the page smaller.

Comment: no i'm talking about scrolling up/down... you can scroll a 100% div off the visible page.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use **positio: fixed**
but I don't believe it will solve the problem, the most indicated in that case is to use an image as your background and then use the background-repeat propertie.

**background-repeat: repeat-x;**

For sure it will solve your problem.

Good Luck.

Answer (score 0):

If I have understan you need this in jQuery:

```
$('#myDiv').width() = $(window).width();

if($('#myDiv').height() > $(window).height()) {
    $('#myDiv').width() = //here put the default size;
}
```

hope it work good for you.